# python cursor and database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

i wrote a simple program like that:

```
def insert1_db(a,cursor,db):
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO RESULT(First_Value) VALUES(?)''',(a))

def insert2_db(b,cursor,db):
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO RESULT(Second_Value) VALUES(?)''',(b))
    db.commit()

#--- Main ---

db_localization = 'c:\\users\\db'  
db = sqlite3.connect(db_localization)                         
cursor = db.cursor() 

a = 10
b = 20

insert1_db(a,cursor,db)
insert1_db(b,cursor,db)
```

In this example the program save the data (a and b) in two separate row, i'd like to know if there is a way to save the data on the same row when in the program there are two or more functions like this example...thanks

Comment: Did you realised both functions are called the same?

Comment: Also, would you mind sharing the CREATE TABLE statement? We need to know whether you have indexes or it's just plain data

Comment: yes sorry, it's the copy and paste :) insert2_db . I've create the database with SquliteBrowser, this simple database have only one table with two column First_value,Second_value without primary key or other things

Comment: Just to summarise, either you have a unique id that allows you to select the row you want to UPDATE with the second value or you cannot do it in 2 stages as you may end up editing a different row. In any case, the 2nd sql command needs to be UPDATE instead of INSERT, as the row is not new.

Comment: it works with update

Comment: Glad you made it to work. Happy coding!